# How to automatically use alternated 2 colors in excel rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like that excel automatically paint in an alternated patern the lines/rows, zebra like effect.

is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Have you tried these yet?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/apply-shading-to-alternate-rows-in-a-worksheet-HA010251644.aspx, http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format2_2010.php

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format2.php did the trick, thanks! Now how do I remove some colored region?

Comment: =mod(row();2)=1

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

=ISODD(COLUMN())

You can change the format to whatever you like.
Highlight column A, go to Conditional format, select "Use a formula..."

[image]

Comment: Right idea, though the original poster is actually looking for `=ISODD(ROW())`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way might be to convert selected range to a Table (Select range, Insert > Tables -Table, OK.)